# Cron not working when called from SSH php curl - Elysia cron module activated

Tags: cron

I have [Elysia cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) module activated, with some cron task scheduled.

I have a crontab pointing to an sh every */2 minutes. The sh executes a php with a curl call to `cron.php?cron_key=CRON-KEY`. It was working perfectly some weeks ago. Suddenly, it has stopped working. When I launch the same cron.php address by browser, it works perfectly, executes the cron with all the scheduled tasks in order as defined by Elysia config.

But when the same cron.php is called via the SSH php (console or just through the cron daemon), it does not work. It gives no error or hint, just does not do anything. I have tested curl in the same domain, with GET parameters, to a different php file, and it is working. I have no idea what can be happening, I have re-installed Elysia cron, and the same results. I cannot understand why Drupal knows that the script is called via a non-browser script and why it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging (too much debugging, I am afraid), I discovered that the problem was in that the cron did not go through all the steps (bootstrap). The problem (which was not logged) was in the [Domain Access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), in which I deleted the English language in one of the domain. IMHO, this is a bug, but not sure if of the module, the core or what. I cannot afford wasting 8 hours of my time looking for errors when I make a simple change that, in principle, should not affect the entire performance of Drupal. This is the kind of things that make Drupal not trustworthy.